# Extremely weird hibernate search issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm having a hard time thinking how to provide a reproducible example, because there are a lot of moving parts. The basics are, I have a Spring Boot application using a JpaRepository, and I'm trying to search for a record with the string `A40-CN0249RN2A` in one column, and am not able to get search results. Here are some data points I'll throw out to show where I've been:

- Using SpringBoot 2
- Using JpaRepository
- Using Hibernate
- Using Postgres
- I've confirmed the column has the data
- I've confirmed in a findAll() search that the data appears in a result entity
- I've logged the query and the bind variables and confirmed that the sql gets results in a sql client
- One SO article told me the dash was suspect. Regarding the dash:

  - I'm able to search results on a different column with a dash
  - I've confirmed that the dash I can search and the one I can't are the same ascii value
  - I've replaced the dash with an _ wildcard and still cannot get results
  - I cannot get results with `A40-CN0249RN2A`, but I can get results on the column with `A40-` and with `-CN0249RN2A` and with `-`

So lost and out of ideas. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is there possibly leading/trailing whitespace with the value?

Comment: @PaulT. No, afraid I checked for character length - also, if it was trailing space in the db column, the url search term would not have had it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing 2 days spent on this, and impossible to find from my description:

Spring Data paging starts with page 0, not page 1. You can get a lot of very diverse difficult-to-track-down errors with just this!